# My netbook battery won't charge (0%) how can I detect what's faulty?

Tags: netbook, battery, eee-pc, charging

I have read here and there on superuser and it looks like I could have:

- Faulty recharge circuitry
- Faulty battery
- Faulty power adapter

How can I be sure to change the right part?

The netbook is an Asus Eee PC 1215n and it looks like it has no calibration tool in bios.
The battery died from a day to another (last week it lasted 5 hours, now 0 seconds).
The netbook works if I connect the powerplug and battery but as soon as I disconnect the powerplug it dies: battery won't last a single second.

Battery led is blinking like if it is charging. I've tried 2 different operating systems (windows 7 and ubuntu) and I get the same result: Battery in charge: 0% even charging for many hours. I think (if I'm lucky) that I'll get the change to test a friend's power adapter during this week end but I still have no clues.

Asus offered me the chance to repair the netbook under warranty but if they find out that parts are not faulty I'm gonna pay money so I want to be sure that something is really broken and I also have the horror they'll keep the netbook for a month, scratch it, lose data (I'll backup it, I know) and other sad things so if I'm sure to solve buying a new battery I'd happily do it... I just want to be sure not to waste money.

Comment: Update: I've sent the netbook to Asus and my recharge circuitry was faulty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since all of the parts are from Asus it is Asus hardware that is at fault. In this situation, I wouldn't even test he parts individually. Asus is better equipped to test for what is wrong then you are. Just make sure to do the basic troubleshooting steps given to you by Asus support. They can certify that it is not operator error and help you process the warranty service.

I would always expect that laptop warranty service to take upwards of a month. Always ask the service rep for an expected timetable to replacement/repair. Ask if they can send you a replacement once they verify the problem. That is the fastest way to get a system back.

Always backup your data before sending out your system and always delete any personal data on the laptop. While the techs probably don't care what is on there, you never know.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Since the notebook works when plugged in, I would think it is *not* the power adapter.

The adapter is the easiest component to test in isolation. Use a Volt-ohmmeter and see if it is putting out as much DC voltage as it says on the boilerplate.

By using different operating systems, you seem to have reduced the likelihood of faulty software.

Can you swap out your battery with a friend's Asus battery? Or buy a cheap replacement battery from eBay? That would eliminate "Faulty Battery." An extra battery would come in handy and you will probably need to replace it before your HDD goes.

If it's still under warranty, by all means, send it in and let Asus diagnose. Cloning your HDD beforehand would be a wise precaution. There are many free utilities. I have used one based on Knoppix that was painless.